# Convert a dataframe into json string in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm a bit new to Spark and Scala.I have a (large ~ 1million) Scala Spark DataFrame, and I need to make it a json String.
the schema of the df like this

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
        |--valKey(String)
        |--vslScore(Double)
```

key is product id and, value is some produt set and it's score values that I get from a parquet file.
I only manage to get something like this. For curly brackets I simply concatenate them to result.

```
3434343<tab>{smartphones:apple:0.4564879,smartphones:samsung:0.723643 }
```

But I expect a value like this.Each value should have a

```
3434343<tab>{"smartphones:apple":0.4564879, "smartphones:samsung":0.723643 }
```

are there anyway that I directly convert this into a Json string without concatenate anything. I hope to write output files into `.csv` format. This is code I'm using

```
 val df = parquetReaderDF.withColumn("key",col("productId"))         
       .withColumn("value", struct(
         col("productType"),
         col("brand"),
         col("score")))
       .select("key","value")
```

> ```
> val df2 = df.withColumn("valKey", concat(
>   col("productType"),lit(":")
>   ,col("brand"),lit(":"),
>
>   col("score")))
>   .groupBy("key")
>   .agg(collect_list(col("valKey")))
>   .map{ r =>
>     val key = r.getAs[String]("key")
>     val value = r.getAs[Seq[String]]  ("collect_list(valKey)").mkString(",")
>
>     (key,value)
>   }
>   .toDF("key", "valKey")
>   .withColumn("valKey", concat(lit("{"), col("valKey"),  lit("}")))
>
>
>   df.coalesce(1)
>        .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
>        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
>        .option("delimiter", "\t")
>        .option("header", "false")
>        .option("quoteMode", "yes")
>        .save("data.csv")
> ```

Comment: Hello @panther, please provide an exact example of input and output data and also a sample of the current code

Comment: can you just not write out your dataframe into Json directly using Df.write.json.path (path) ? Also, collect_list  and coalesce(1) will be expensive.  If you need to get one big file out use hdfs  after your part files are written.

Comment: This for actually testing purposes. I've tried. I need a tab space after product id. It's easy to use CSV format. Otherwise this using json directly wrap all the values into quotes including product id. I don't need to happen that.